# How can Christians be assured they are truly saved and that Jesus won't say "Depart from me I never knew you." on judgement day?

Tags: assurance-of-salvation

In the Bible, it says God knows everything about us- intimately. So, if He KNOWS us, how could He NOT know us and tell us to depart from Him? I'm so confused. I thought I was saved, been to church, pray, speak to Jesus and pray to Him CONSTANTLY. But lately I've been feeling abandoned by Him and it has caused me to completely lose faith in Him. Feels like He couldn't be farther from me and like He doesn't love me. I have been so hard on myself and really spent a lot of time in introspection trying to figure out what I could be doing wrong. I'm not perfect, but I've left so much of my sinful ways behind. I also wonder if I truly am saved. Do Christians absolutely HAVE to be baptized? Maybe that's my problem- maybe I need to get baptized(?) I just don't understand why I'm feeling this way. I hope someone can give me answers to all my questions because I'm desperate for answers. TIA and God bless.

Comment: At the top of the page (on the right) is this statement : _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._ This is not to discourage anyone from private seeking of the Lord. It is a necessary caution that the internet is an anonymous place in which strangers congregate. Your question is deeply personal. I experienced exactly the same as you express, when I was young. Now my faith is stronger. (I am 69 years old.)

Comment: I too, have feel this way regularly, and an honest conversation with a close Christian friend has been the only thing that has helped. That said, this website is a great resource for specific questions, so perhaps you could ask a new question with one specific point in in. For example, you might consider rephrasing your question on baptism as "Does [your denomination] teach that Christians must be baptised?"

Comment: What denomination are you asking about? Different denominations will likely have different answers.

Comment: Are you seriously asking for answers from non-Christians? You need to select an appropriate Tag to get answers from people who share the same faith. Please take our Tour to understand how this site is different and what makes for a good, acceptable question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Lesley, it's not obvious what the `non-christians` tag actually means (like so many others, it has no description).  But really, any question asked on this site should be asked in a way that it *can* be answered by a non-Christian (which is why this current question is perhaps unsuitable in its current form). My own answer for instance is simply an objective explanation of the "depart" reference in the question, not requiring any specific belief on my own part.

Comment: There's a great line from a song, 'only by grace can I stand'. It is not by works or keeping commandments or trying to be perfect - it is by Christ's sacrifice on our behalf that God grants us life - salvation and eternity with Him. Notice Phil 2:13

>for it is God who is at work in you, both to will and to work for His good pleasure.

Unpacking it tells us that God is working to grant 'the will' AND the 'ability' to do what pleases Him. It's all God's doing, not ours, we simply and thankfully and humbly respond to His presence in us and wait till our change - He doesn't want to lose one!

Comment: Dear Ashley, "Whomever comes to me I will never cast out. - John 6:37".  Please read John's 1st Letter.  The stated purpose of that letter is that those who believe that Jesus is the Son of God may KNOW that they have eternal life.  Even your current struggle sounds like signs of life to me.  Put your trust in Jesus...He will never leave you or forsake you.  The ones He tells to depart are the ones who never truly came to Him.

Comment: 39 One of the criminals who were hanged railed at him, saying, “Are you not the Christ? Save yourself and us!” 40 But the other rebuked him, saying, “Do you not fear God, since you are under the same sentence of condemnation? 41 And we indeed justly, for we are receiving the due reward of our deeds; but this man has done nothing wrong.” 42 And he said, “Jesus, remember me when you come into your kingdom.” 43 And he said to him, “Truly, I say to you, today you will be with me in paradise.” 

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version. (2016). (Lk 23:39–43). Wheaton, IL: Crossway Bibles.

Answer (score 1):

Your "*tell us to depart from Him*" comes from Matthew 7:23.
But notice what the beginning of the speech says:

> “Not everyone who says to Me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ shall enter the kingdom of heaven, but he **who does the will of My Father** in heaven.
> “Many will say to Me in that day, ‘Lord, Lord, have we not prophesied in Your name, cast out demons in Your name, and done many wonders in Your name?’
> “And then I will declare to them, ‘I never knew you; depart from Me, **you who practice lawlessness**!’
> — Mat 7:21–23

In other words, it's not enough to simply go through the motions of being a Christian; one must truly do the will of the Father.

To expand on @adam's answer, about believing and loving, there is one obvious sign that we are following that advice:

> … But if you want to enter into life, keep the commandments.”
> — Mat 19:17

> If you love Me, keep My commandments.
> — Jhn 14:15

> He who has My commandments and keeps them, it is he who loves Me. And he who loves Me will be loved by My Father, and I will love him and manifest Myself to him.
> — Jhn 14:21

> If you keep My commandments, you will abide in My love, just as I have kept My Father's commandments and abide in His love.
> — Jhn 15:10

> For this is the love of God, that we keep His commandments. And His commandments are not burdensome.
> — 1Jo 5:3

> Here is the patience of the saints; here are those who keep the commandments of God and the faith of Jesus.
> — Rev 14:12

> Blessed are those who do His commandments, that they may have the right to the tree of life, and may enter through the gates into the city.
> — Rev 22:14

Comment: and what are those commandments?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is rather simple...
Paul answers this question beautifully in Acts 16...

"Believe on the Lord Jesus Christ and thou shall be saved" (Acts 16.31)

And of course, the gospel of Mark has another gem...

30 And you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart, with all your soul, with all your mind, and with all your strength.’ This is the first commandment. 31 And the second, like it, is this: ‘You shall love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no other commandment greater than these.”(Mark 12:30-31)